# Looping parameterized query

Tags: c#, mysql, loops

I've been looking for its solution for some time now, I've seen similar questions here on SO but the answers there didn't solve my problem. In my situation, I would like to loop through the rows of datagridview values to insert it to MySql database. The number of rows in the datagridview will depend on the user. When I try to input 2 or more rows of datagridview values and try to insert it to the database, only the first row of data is inserted successfully.

Here is my code:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
                cmd.Connection = SecurityMod.dbconn();
                for (int i = 0; i < dgv_ctrl.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string sql = "INSERT INTO delivery(DeliveryNumber, CreationDate, Client, Product, Price, Quantity, Total) " +
                             "VALUES(@num_Delivery, " + "@dgv_datevalue" + ", " +
                             "@name_Client" + ", " +
                             "@name_Product" + ", " +
                             "@priceof_Produt" + ", " +
                             "@quan_Product" + ", " +
                             "@price_Total" + ");";

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num_Delivery", num_Delivery);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dgv_datevalue", DateTime.Parse(dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Creation_Date"].Value.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_Client", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Client_name"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_Product", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Product_name"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceof_Produt", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Price_ofProduct"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quan_Product", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity_ofProduct"].Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_Total", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Total_Price"].Value);
                    cmd.CommandText = sql;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

The error: Parameter '@num_Delivery' has already been defined. I'm new at using C# language. Any ideas and suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: You need to clear the parameter before adding for 2nd row like this `cmd.Parameters.Clear();`

Comment: Just to make sure I get it right, I would use cmd.Parameters.Clear(); after cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); ?

Comment: Add it before all your parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
```

in the *for* loop:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO delivery(DeliveryNumber, CreationDate, Client, Product, Price, Quantity, Total) " +
             "VALUES(@num_Delivery, " + "@dgv_datevalue" + ", " +
             "@name_Client" + ", " +
             "@name_Product" + ", " +
             "@priceof_Produt" + ", " +
             "@quan_Product" + ", " +
             "@price_Total" + ");";
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_ctrl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = SecurityMod.dbconn();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num_Delivery", num_Delivery);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dgv_datevalue", DateTime.Parse(dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Creation_Date"].Value.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_Client", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Client_name"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_Product", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Product_name"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceof_Produt", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Price_ofProduct"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quan_Product", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity_ofProduct"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_Total", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Total_Price"].Value);
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

or clear its *Parameters* collection:

```
string sql = "INSERT INTO delivery(DeliveryNumber, CreationDate, Client, Product, Price, Quantity, Total) " +
             "VALUES(@num_Delivery, " + "@dgv_datevalue" + ", " +
             "@name_Client" + ", " +
             "@name_Product" + ", " +
             "@priceof_Produt" + ", " +
             "@quan_Product" + ", " +
             "@price_Total" + ");";
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = SecurityMod.dbconn();
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_ctrl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num_Delivery", num_Delivery);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dgv_datevalue", DateTime.Parse(dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Creation_Date"].Value.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_Client", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Client_name"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_Product", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Product_name"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceof_Produt", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Price_ofProduct"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quan_Product", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity_ofProduct"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_Total", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Total_Price"].Value);
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

*Sql* string can be out of loop.

Comment: Moving that alone will not help when you have `cmd.Connection = SecurityMod.dbconn();` outside the loop. Also, will result in build error

Comment: Obviously move also all relative rows.

Comment: When post the solution, please post the complete solution. Sometimes, we can not expect them to do it themeselves, unless we mentioned in the solution.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But, I'm curious why is it working even if the sql query is outside the for loop. Shouldn't it be an error or something?

Comment: slq is a string so it's immutable. Parameters will change in the loop not sql string.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this. It should work.

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.Connection = SecurityMod.dbconn();
for (int i = 0; i < dgv_ctrl.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string sql = "INSERT INTO delivery(DeliveryNumber, CreationDate, Client, Product, Price, Quantity, Total) " +
             "VALUES(@num_Delivery, " + "@dgv_datevalue" + ", " +
             "@name_Client" + ", " +
             "@name_Product" + ", " +
             "@priceof_Produt" + ", " +
             "@quan_Product" + ", " +
             "@price_Total" + ");";
    cmd.Parameter.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@num_Delivery", num_Delivery);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dgv_datevalue", DateTime.Parse(dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Creation_Date"].Value.ToString()).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_Client", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Client_name"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name_Product", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Product_name"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@priceof_Produt", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Price_ofProduct"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@quan_Product", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Quantity_ofProduct"].Value);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price_Total", dgv_ctrl.Rows[i].Cells["Total_Price"].Value);
    cmd.CommandText = sql;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```